# Refencing a plugin in ChartJs.Blazor

Tags: chart.js, blazor

I am converting an application from standard C# MVC application to a Blazor application. The MVC application uses ChartJs to create charts and graphs. The one thing I have not been able to figure out is how to call a plugin in ChartJs.Blazor.  Here is my plugin that works correctly in the MVC application using Javascript version of ChartJs:

```
 Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeUpdate: function (chartInstance) {
            chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                if (dataset.label === "CPAP Usage") {
                    dataset.backgroundColor = dataset.data.map(function (data) {
                        return data < 4 ? '#7d1646' : '#40a37f';
                    })

                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is put the JavaScript code in a JavaScript file in the `wwwroot/css` directory. This would be the contents for that file:

```
export function MakePluginService() {
    Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeUpdate: function (chartInstance) {
            chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                if (dataset.label === "CPAP Usage") {
                    dataset.backgroundColor = dataset.data.map(function (data) 
                   {
                        return data < 4 ? '#7d1646' : '#40a37f';
                    })

                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Put it in a file such as `PlugInService.js`. Add the following lines before the `@code` section:

```
 @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
 @implements IAsyncDisposable
```

Then, in the `@code` section, add the following lines:

```
private IJSObjectReference? module;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", 
            "./PlugInService.js");
        if (module is not null)
        {
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("MakePluginService");
        }

    }
}

async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
{
    if (module is not null)
    {
        await module.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

The JavaScript file will be executed after the HTML content is rendered. In the `MakePluginService`, a ChartJs service will be registered with the `Blazor.ChartJs` library.